# Elements between page breaks after each tabular row in BIRT

Tags: birt

I have a report design where I have to display each row of a table in separate pages as header and on each page I need to display separate body. In BIRT, if I set the page break property for table as always, I can see the data on separate pages but I am not able to insert other elements in between these rows. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add multiple `Detail` rows. In first you'll have what you have recently, in second you can put whatever you like, just treat it as a grid.